# Why is the error here at most $\frac{1}{3}$?

Tags: proof-explanation, machine-learning

From Understanding Machine Learning: Theory and Algorithms:

Can someone explain why the text in the red box below is true?  Why does the probability have to be $ \le \frac{1}{3}$?  Why can't we have a single region having probability $> \frac{1}{3}$?

The definition of weak learner is included below.

---

[image]

Comment: If all three piece have probability bigger than 1/3 then...

Comment: I edited my question.  Why can't we have a single region with error larger than $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Sure you can, but you will also have a region with at most 1/3 probability.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  I misread that.  It said ONE of the regions must have probability less than $1/3$.  Which is shown in your first comment.